# Keycloak API get total count of users that have the specified role name

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

As the title suggests, I want to be able to get a total count of users having a specific role in order to make my pagination work.

```
GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/users?first=0&max=5
```

This only returns the array of users but there is no total count result. How can I get the total count value for my endpoint?

Comment: There are no count API for `GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/users`